# ReactJS react-pdf error "Failed to load PDF file." on some attempts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, webpack, react-pdf

I created a react js app with `create-react-app` and I am trying out `react-pdf` to view pdfs. the problem I have is that my code works sometimes and sometimes doesn't. when I first load the app the pdf always loads well but if i visit other links/urls on the site and then navigate to the page with the pdf, the pdf will likely fail to load on a few attempts with an error "Failed to load PDF file".

> if error it looks like below image
> [image]

> if success it look like below image
> [image]

this is how i have implemented it

> imports

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack';
import { useState } from 'react';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';
```

> code implementation

```
function ReactPDF() {
    const imageKitURL = ' https://ik.imagekit.io/kwmvfjr0r';
    const pdf = `${imageKitURL}/test_files/file-example_PDF_1MB.pdf`;

    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

    function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
        setNumPages(numPages);
        setPageNumber(1);
    }

    function changePage(offset) {
        setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + offset);
    }

    function previousPage() {
        changePage(-1);
    }

    function nextPage() {
        changePage(1);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Page {pageNumber || (numPages ? 1 : '--')} of {numPages || '--'}
                </p>
                <button type="button" disabled={pageNumber <= 1} onClick={previousPage}>
                    Previous
                </button>
                <button type="button" disabled={pageNumber >= numPages} onClick={nextPage}>
                    Next
                </button>
            </div>
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind */}
            <Document file={pdf} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
                <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
            </Document>
        </>
    );
}
```

i hope the question is detailed enough to explain the situation

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the types with the command:

> npm i -D @types/react-pdf